# systemd timer: Get last execution in 8601 format

Tags: bash, systemd, date, timer

Is it possible to get the last execution time from a systemd timer?

Example:

```
systemctl list-timers dnf-automatic.timer
NEXT                          LEFT     LAST                          PASSED  UNIT                ACTIVATES
Wed 2017-04-12 08:02:56 CEST  21h left Mon 2017-04-10 15:49:27 CEST  18h ago dnf-automatic.timer dnf-automatic.service
```

Is there a command which would print the `LAST` column in ISO8601 format? Or do I need to go the hard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `systemd` units' properties can be queried by:

```
systemctl show $unit
```

Individual properties can be queried by:

```
systemctl show $unit -p $property --value
```

Technically, this isn't an answer to your question because timers are not "executed", but suppose you want to look at the unit the timer referred to, then you can query its last "start" time with:

```
systemctl show $unit -p ExecMainStartTimestamp --value
```

and its last "stop" time with:

```
systemctl show $unit -p ExecMainExitTimestamp --value
```

These produce outputs in the form of `So 2017-04-16 19:19:12 UTC` (on my system for my locale) which is neither ISO 8601 nor feedable to (GNU) `date`.  But if you set `LC_TIME` in the invocation to `C`, you can process the data further (provided you use GNU `date` or a similar tool):

```
date --date="$(LC_TIME=C systemctl show $unit -p ExecMainExitTimestamp --value)" -I
```

This will (for example) return `2017-04-16`.

Prior to version 230, `systemd` did not provide a `--value` option and instead returned the property value preceded by the property name and an equal sign.  In that case you have to extract the property's value from the data yourself, for example with `sed`:

```
date --date="$(LC_TIME=C systemctl show $unit -p ExecMainExitTimestamp | sed -e 's/^[^=]\+=//;')" -I
```

Comment: thanks, but `--value` does not seem to work. "unrecognized option"
`systemd 229`

Comment: I have added some code for `systemd` < 230 which did not have a `--value` option (cf. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS).

Comment: The last time a timer fired is `LastTriggerUSec`